# How can I create a torch tensor from a numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have created a code that generates a matrix with shape `(12,12)` for color image analyzes using convolutional neural network.
The input of my script is a [torch](/questions/tagged/torch) tensor of shape `(5,3,12,12)`. I took off the values 5 and 3 using `detach().numpy()`.

The script :

```
    for k in range(5):
            for l in range(3):
                y=x[k][l].detach().numpy()
                m,n= y.shape
                im=np.pad(y,((1,1),(1,1)),'constant')
                Enhanced = np.zeros((m,n))
                for i in range(1,m+1):
                    for j in range(1,n+1):
                        ...      
                z.append(Enhanced)
```

`...` represents a simple function which I don't want to bother you with.

z is a list of the Enhanced which are [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) arrays.
so my goal is to create a torch tensor from the Enhanced numpy arrays with shape `(5,3,12,12)`.

I added this line to my code inside the for loop and i get:

```
 r=torch.Tensor(z)
 print(r.shape)
```

and then print the r.shape and i get that :

```
 torch.Size([3, 12, 12])
 torch.Size([6, 12, 12])
 torch.Size([9, 12, 12])
 torch.Size([12, 12, 12])
 torch.Size([15, 12, 12])
```

So what I understand is that I need to stack those r tensors.
I used the function `t=np.stack(r)`
but what I get is the shape of the last execution which is `torch.Size([15, 12, 12])`
so how can I modify that to get shape of `(5, 3, 12, 12)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to:

- stack list of `np.array` together (`Enhanced` ones)
- convert it to PyTorch tensors via `torch.from_numpy` function

For example:

```
import numpy as np

some_data = [np.random.randn(3, 12, 12) for _ in range(5)]

stacked = np.stack(some_data)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(stacked)
```

Please note that **each `np.array` in the `list` has to be of the same shape**

For different shapes one could do that:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

some_data = [np.random.randn(3, 12, 12) for _ in range(5)] + [
    np.random.randn(6, 12, 12)
]

stacked = np.concatenate(some_data).reshape(-1, 3, 12, 12)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(stacked)

print(tensor.shape)
```

In your case:

```
r = torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(z).reshape(-1, 3, 12, 12))
```